# SQL Server,query to get values between todays date and tomorrow date plus adding 14 hours to both the dates

Tags: sql-server

I have to get the values from table and display gridview of selected values between today and tomorrow date,my hosting company is 14 hours behind my time,so i have to add 14 hours to my code.I wrote the query and it is executing but doesnt give any values 
Here is the query below

```
SELECT * FROM [customerdetails] 
where date between dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d, 1, getdate())))) 
  and dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
```

Can anyone please help me out,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between operator expects BETWEEN Lower_End AND Upper_End

You have your query written as BETWEEN  Upper_End AND Lower_End , hence no results are coming back.

```
SELECT * FROM [customerdetails] 
where date between dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) 
 and  dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d, 1, getdate()))))
```

or Even better option would be

```
SELECT * FROM [customerdetails] 
where [date] >= dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) 
 and  [date] <= dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(d, 1, getdate()))))
```

Comment: I tried the below query and my own query which i gave above (after correcting it)in both caes i am getting tomorrows date but not todays date,any idea what is going wrong?is it because at my place now the time is 12:00 p.m plus 14 hours means tomorrow,am i right in this assumption?

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, because I don't have access to SQL Server right now.  But it looks like your query is looking "between tomorrow and today".  Try switching the order so the query is looking "between today and tomorrow".  According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx), it looks like the order matters.

Comment: you are right @thejonwithnoh,it is working now .But with the above query i am getting only tomorrows date ,but not today

Comment: is it because at my place now the time is 12:00 p.m plus 14 hours means tomorrow,am i right in this assumption? I didnt upload my files in hosting server yet ,so i cant tell as still some other works have to be completed before uploading

Comment: @vamsikrishna Perhaps you should adjust for the timezone before casting to a date, so that the code for "today" becomes `convert(datetime, convert(date, dateadd(hh, 14, getdate())))` (and analogously for tomorrow)? I can't be sure without knowing the specifics of how your data is stored and exactly the type of date range you're looking for, but this would be my best guess.

Comment: i checked a few queries like for adjusting to the timezone,but they require to alter the table or merge two tables and it is bit complex.I have a grid view and it displays a table with normal select query ,as of now i just want to get the table data for only todays date as of now (after this is working i will modify query to get today and tomorrow details)but with current query i am not able to get either today or even tomorrow date.This is my query,i dont get any value at all,       SELECT * FROM [customerdetails] where [date] = dateadd(hh, 14, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))

Comment: i dont want to make too many modifications and keep it simple ,possibly thorugh the select statemnt only ,is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
date between 
dateadd(hh,14,cast(getdate() as date)) 
and dateadd(hh,14,dateadd(d,1,cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: hello,why is it -14,shouldnt it be +14?My timezone is 14 hours ahead of my hosting server so shouldnt it be +14